# Closing Other android App with java Intent

Tags: java, android

I open YouTube app using intent But unable to close it as it is not part of our context.

I search a lot on the internet but unable to find.
Here is a code for an open activity that I use.

```
String urlStr ="vnd.youtube:"+Vedio_r;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(urlStr));
startActivity(intent);
```

I new a function that closes that app which was opened by me!

Comment: I think if you want that. You have to implement webview in your app with the Url.

Comment: Please describe how to do that thing!

Comment: there's no way you can close an external app, but you can instead bring your own app to the foreground

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to control things that is out of your app context.

Comment: Hi Nyi please add more context  to your question quickly !